# Download file in Webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, android-studio

I'm using *webview* in an Android application. I am trying to download a ***.pdf*** file, however when the link is clicked through the application the .pdf file name is changed to ***"1rcPnhg9_rSes92BiQPotVjXuEAfFnyrf.pdf"***, and is not saved with the original file name.

How to make webview save the file with the original name? At the moment the webview is saving the file using the ID as the name.

**Used link:** https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1rcPnhg9_rSes92BiQPotVjXuEAfFnyrf

**WebView:**

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
                                        long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));
                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setDescription("Downloading File...");
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                                url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }});
```

**Permissions in Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/>
```

Comment: URLUtil.guessFileName doesn't ask the document for a file name, but tries to guess the file name from just the URL. If the file name you want isn't in the URL, it's not going to get there. You'll need to supply the file name from elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a test with your link (in Kotlin). If you need a Java example, please, let me know:

```
private fun test() {
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)

    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            Log.d(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading:url = ${url}")
            if (url.contains("=download")){
                Log.d(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading: ")
                downloadFile(url)
                webView.stopLoading()
            }
            return true
        }
    }
    val url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1rcPnhg9_rSes92BiQPotVjXuEAfFnyrf"
    webView.loadUrl(url)
}

fun downloadFile(url: String) {
    Log.d(TAG, "downloadFile: url = $url")
    val manager = getSystemService(Activity.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    val uri =
        Uri.parse(url)
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
    val reference: Long = manager.enqueue(request)
}
```

[image abuot download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU26V.png)

Java code:

```
    private void test() {

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.contains("=download")){
                downloadFile(url);
            }

            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });

    String url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1rcPnhg9_rSes92BiQPotVjXuEAfFnyrf";
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

private void downloadFile(String url) {
    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Activity.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    manager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh magic! :D  I'm trying to write the same in
Java, but it's not working yet, could you help me?

Comment: I write a Java code. What do you see? Is there an error or something else?

Comment: I made the java code. I modified my answer with it

Comment: Appears cannot resolve symbol fun

Comment: Which one? Where is the problem?

Comment: Maybe you should use "Invalidate Caches" function from File menu in Android Studio

Comment: Ohhh it worked like magic. Thank you so much for the help and learning. :D

Answer (score 0):

An option to use DownloadManager

For this you sould add an onNavigating event to your WebView. If the user target a pdf file you can stop the loading process with: ags.Cancel = true
And this point when you can pass the url to a DownloadManager what will download your file.

Comment: I understand, but how could I put this inside the code? Sorry if it seems too obvious, I'm new to android studio

Comment: I wrote a new answer with a sample

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple code

```
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            if (url.contains(".pdf")){
                downloadFile(url)
            }
            return false
        }
    }

    fun downloadFile(url: String) {
    Log.d(TAG, "downloadFile: url = $url")
    val manager = getSystemService(Activity.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    val uri =
        Uri.parse(url)
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
    val reference: Long = manager.enqueue(request)
}
```